# extra condition inside ternary operator possible?

Tags: c#

I have condition

```
        string columns = (protocol == null || protocol == 5) ? "Patient Id,Patient Initial,DOB,Age,Height,Weight,BMI,Occupation,Nationality,Education,Race,Gender,MaritalStatus," : "Patient Id,";
```

so its basically setting a string.

here i am checking just protocolt type and setting string as in the above code,

no i have some flags

```
  var age=false;
  var gender=false;
```

Normally if condition is true(protocl=5) the string contain age and gender;

i want to know in the same code i show above, i need to make some changes, i have two flags right?

if age==true; then only the string should contain age.
if gender==false the string should not contain gender.

is it possible to put this condition check in the first one line code itself?

what is the best and less coded way to implement that?

Comment: _"what is the best and less coded way to implement that?"_ The best way isn't necessarily always to write code as short as possible and try to fit it all in one line.  Write code that is easy for _you_ to understand and maintain.

Comment: Don't forget - easy for *others* to understand and maintain too :)

Comment: The logic is not really clear. Your conditional operator just checks if protocol is null or 5 and then returns all fields(not only  age and gender as mentioned), otherwise it returns `"Patient Id,"`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well keep it simple and split it into two parts:

1. Create a list of the columns you want
2. Convert the list into a comma-separated string

Yes, it's longer and uses a bit more memory. But it's also easier to see what it's doing and to change the logic in future:

```
int? protocol = 5;
var age = false;
var gender = false;

var columnList = new List<string>();
columnList.Add("Patient Id");

if (protocol == null || protocol == 5)
{
    columnList.Add("Patient Initial");
    columnList.Add("DOB");

    if (age)
    {
        columnList.Add("Age");
    }

    columnList.Add("Height");
    columnList.Add("Weight");
    columnList.Add("BMI");
    columnList.Add("Occupation");
    columnList.Add("Nationality");
    columnList.Add("Education");
    columnList.Add("Race");

    if (gender)
    {
        columnList.Add("Gender");
    }

    columnList.Add("MaritalStatus");
}

string columns = string.Join(",", columnList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int? protocol = 5;
        bool age = true;
        var gender = true;
        string columns = "";
        if (protocol == 5)
        {
            columns += "Patient Id,";
        }

        if (age)
        {
            columns += "Age,";
        }

        if (gender)
        {
            columns += "Gender,";

        }
        columns += columns.TrimEnd(',');
```

add as many if as you want. Using ternary operator will make it complex.

Comment: could you explain? think i have flag for each item in the string, if the respective flag is true it should show that, otherwise it should not show that. so for each item i have to check condition.like dob, age, height, ..etc all has respective flags.

Comment: its returning age because boolean age=true. do you want to manage it other way??